# (Python) How to import video files from a folder into an array?

Tags: python, arrays, video, directory, shuffle

I plan on trying to make my own shuffle system and output them to VLC but I'm not sure how I would go about importing the contents of the folder into an array (I have a good few hundred videos)

Answer (score 0):

```
from random import shuffle
from glob import glob

filelist = shuffle(glob(r"/path/to/dir/*.mp4"))
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, this seems to have worked. Is there a way of viewing the contents of the array?

Comment: Great! You can use `print(filelist)` to see the contents. Feel free to upvote answers to your question and please [accept](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) the answer if it solved your issue.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, when I do that it just prints "None"

The code is:
`import vlc
import os
from random import shuffle
from glob import glob

videolist = shuffle(glob(r"L:\Music\Artists\33 - Daft Punk - Discovery"))

print(videolist)`

Comment: Try this: `shuffle(glob(r"L:\Music\Artists\33 - Daft Punk - Discovery\*"))`

Comment: That worked thanks :), I also edited it to allow for directories to be entered too for any passer bys here it is:

`glob(shuffle("dir", "r"))`

Going to do some more advanced shuffling further down the line